# I can't compile the GMP Library (for c or c++) on my Windows desktop

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin, mingw-w64, gmp

I need GMP for a windows C++ project.

I am using CygWin for the bash and compiler.
The GMP Docs recommend CygWin (and Mingw), so technically it should do it.

My error occurs when i "make" the project after

```
autoconf 
./configure --prefix "Some_Path_to_build"
make
```

and the error is following

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_fib_table -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=znver1 -march=znver1 -c fib_table.c -o fib_table.o
In file included from fib_table.c:4:
../gmp-impl.h:146:10: fatal error: ../gmp-mparam.h: Invalid argument
 #include "gmp-mparam.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:492: fib_table.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/SDK/gmp-6.2.1/mpn'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:997: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/SDK/gmp-6.2.1'
make: *** [Makefile:787: all] Error 2
```

I opened the gmp-impl.h file into VS Code, and it actually said: can't find header, if i hover over the `#include <gmp-mparam.h>` part. Just like if you inlcude a header which is not in any default include directory. **BUT** I (double) checked it and the header is in the right directory.

I compiled it multiple times on Linux (Ubuntu) with the same commands and it works just fine.

### EDIT

as i found out today, there must be something wrong with the header-file. I can open `gmp-mparam.h`, but it is empty and when i try to edit it or rather save it, i throws an unknown error.

Comment: If you go to the directory that contains `fib_table.c`, then `gmp-mparam.h` should be in the [immediate] parent directory. But, I'd examine line 46 of `gmp-impl.h`. I'm _not_ sure about `autoconf/configure`, but I've always done: `./configure --prefix="Some_path_to_build"` But, for most such configure scripts, `--prefix` usually specifies the prefix for _install_ (e.g. `--prefix=/usr/local`). Try: `./configure --help`

Comment: i must use --prefix because otherwise it it tries to install it to /usr/local, which doesnt exist in windows and the bash has no right to, i fixed it by using --prefix

Comment: You're using `cygwin`, so it has its own hierarchy. It _does_ have `/usr/local`. With cygwin, if you do _not_ use `/cygdrive/whatever`, it will assume the root directory is (e.g.) `/path_to_cygwin` [aka `C:\\cygwin64`] and `/usr/local` will be relative to that. Also, cygwin has its own version of `gcc`, so why not use it? It _may_ be possible, but the usual is to go wholy `mingw` or wholy `cygwin` rather than trying to intermix the two.

Comment: Run the `cygwin` config/download program. If it hasn't already installed, you can add the `gcc` package [and whatever companion packages you might need]. With luck, `cygwin` has a prebuilt, installable version of the `gmp` library, so you wouldn't need to build/install from source.

Comment: BTW, these days, the cool kids are using `WSL2` [Windows Subsystem for Linux], to boot up _real_ `ubuntu` [or fedora] linux in WSL2's VM. Then, you're running _real_ linux--the `.deb` packages that it would install are the _same_ binary packages you'd install for a native `ubuntu` install linux kernel and filesystem. Similar to `virtualbox`, `xen`, or `vmware`.

Comment: `mingw` would use native Windows PE format `.obj/.dll/.exe`. Cygwin uses POSIX compatible ELF `.so`, etc. These files _are_ part of/accessible from the WinX filesystem. `WSL2` is a VMM (virtual machine manager). It _literally_ boots a real linux kernel under the VM and once the linux kernel has control, it's 100% pure linux (i.e. _no_ WinX whatever). The VMM maps the "disks" that linux uses onto [large] files in NTFS fs. But, it does _not_ look at the individual "linux" files.

Comment: As edited above i looked it up in the docs and CygWin should work to create a .dll

Comment: Yes, I should have looked at my installed cygwin directory. It uses PE format [_not_ ELF as I said previously--my bad]. So, it also uses `.dll` for shared libs. It may [have to] link in some extra cygwin libs/stuff. For POSIX syscalls, there is usually simple translation/wrapper (e.g. `open` --> `FileOpenEx`). But, (e.g.), win32 doesn't support the `fork` syscall [it supports _threads_ and not _processes_]. So, the cygwin library simulates it, internally, by doing a series of calls to torture the kernel into doing the equivalent. This is transparent to the caller.

Comment: If you have Cygwin it's best to do the complete project in the Cygwin environment with the Cygwin toolchain.  Any programs you create are executable from Windows in general.  Cygwin is, and creates, Windows executables and libraries.  Its brilliance is in providing a POSIX environment and API.

Comment: I already tried it, with and without GCC from Mingw and CygWin. Doesn't work at all. Same Error

Comment: Install `libgmp-devel` and `libgmp10` cygwin packages. Cygwin already has the version 6.2.1-1 of those packages; no need to compile anything

Comment: That works, but doesnt _solve_ the problem.
I will use the precompiled libs until i can compile them myself, ty

Answer (score 0):

I also met this error on my computer. I think the soft symbol link cause this error. However, after replace all the symbol link with the true file, I met another problem. The make command stuck on this command.

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8   -o libmpn.la  fib_table.lo mp_bases.lo invert_limb_table.lo add.lo add_1.lo add_n.lo sub.lo sub_1.lo sub_n.lo cnd_add_n.lo cnd_sub_n.lo cnd_swap.lo neg.lo com.lo mul_1.lo addmul_1.lo submul_1.lo add_err1_n.lo add_err2_n.lo add_err3_n.lo sub_err1_n.lo sub_err2_n.lo sub_err3_n.lo lshift.lo rshift.lo dive_1.lo diveby3.lo divis.lo divrem.lo divrem_1.lo divrem_2.lo fib2_ui.lo fib2m.lo mod_1.lo mod_34lsub1.lo mode1o.lo pre_mod_1.lo dump.lo mod_1_1.lo mod_1_2.lo mod_1_3.lo mod_1_4.lo lshiftc.lo mul.lo mul_fft.lo mul_n.lo sqr.lo mul_basecase.lo sqr_basecase.lo nussbaumer_mul.lo mulmid_basecase.lo toom42_mulmid.lo mulmid_n.lo mulmid.lo random.lo random2.lo pow_1.lo rootrem.lo sqrtrem.lo sizeinbase.lo get_str.lo set_str.lo compute_powtab.lo scan0.lo scan1.lo popcount.lo hamdist.lo cmp.lo zero_p.lo perfsqr.lo perfpow.lo strongfibo.lo gcd_11.lo gcd_22.lo gcd_1.lo gcd.lo gcdext_1.lo gcdext.lo gcd_subdiv_step.lo gcdext_lehmer.lo div_q.lo tdiv_qr.lo jacbase.lo jacobi_2.lo jacobi.lo get_d.lo matrix22_mul.lo matrix22_mul1_inverse_vector.lo hgcd_matrix.lo hgcd2.lo hgcd_step.lo hgcd_reduce.lo hgcd.lo hgcd_appr.lo hgcd2_jacobi.lo hgcd_jacobi.lo mullo_n.lo mullo_basecase.lo sqrlo.lo sqrlo_basecase.lo toom22_mul.lo toom32_mul.lo toom42_mul.lo toom52_mul.lo toom62_mul.lo toom33_mul.lo toom43_mul.lo toom53_mul.lo toom54_mul.lo toom63_mul.lo toom44_mul.lo toom6h_mul.lo toom6_sqr.lo toom8h_mul.lo toom8_sqr.lo toom_couple_handling.lo toom2_sqr.lo toom3_sqr.lo toom4_sqr.lo toom_eval_dgr3_pm1.lo toom_eval_dgr3_pm2.lo toom_eval_pm1.lo toom_eval_pm2.lo toom_eval_pm2exp.lo toom_eval_pm2rexp.lo toom_interpolate_5pts.lo toom_interpolate_6pts.lo toom_interpolate_7pts.lo toom_interpolate_8pts.lo toom_interpolate_12pts.lo toom_interpolate_16pts.lo invertappr.lo invert.lo binvert.lo mulmod_bnm1.lo sqrmod_bnm1.lo mulmod_bknp1.lo div_qr_1.lo div_qr_1n_pi1.lo div_qr_2.lo div_qr_2n_pi1.lo div_qr_2u_pi1.lo sbpi1_div_q.lo sbpi1_div_qr.lo sbpi1_divappr_q.lo dcpi1_div_q.lo dcpi1_div_qr.lo dcpi1_divappr_q.lo mu_div_qr.lo mu_divappr_q.lo mu_div_q.lo bdiv_q_1.lo sbpi1_bdiv_q.lo sbpi1_bdiv_qr.lo sbpi1_bdiv_r.lo dcpi1_bdiv_q.lo dcpi1_bdiv_qr.lo mu_bdiv_q.lo mu_bdiv_qr.lo bdiv_q.lo bdiv_qr.lo broot.lo brootinv.lo bsqrt.lo bsqrtinv.lo divexact.lo bdiv_dbm1c.lo redc_1.lo redc_2.lo redc_n.lo powm.lo powlo.lo sec_powm.lo sec_mul.lo sec_sqr.lo sec_div_qr.lo sec_div_r.lo sec_pi1_div_qr.lo sec_pi1_div_r.lo sec_add_1.lo sec_sub_1.lo sec_invert.lo trialdiv.lo remove.lo and_n.lo andn_n.lo nand_n.lo ior_n.lo iorn_n.lo nior_n.lo xor_n.lo xnor_n.lo copyi.lo copyd.lo zero.lo sec_tabselect.lo comb_tables.lo invert_limb.lo sqr_diag_addlsh1.lo mul_2.lo addmul_2.lo addlsh1_n.lo sublsh1_n.lo rsblsh1_n.lo rsh1add_n.lo rsh1sub_n.lo addlsh2_n.lo rsblsh2_n.lo addlsh_n.lo rsblsh_n.lo add_n_sub_n.lo addaddmul_1msb0.lo
```

Comment: I finished compile by using msys. No error meeted;